# When to use present continuous

Tags: present-continuous

If something is planned you have been imposed, can that be considered as an arrangment to use present continuous?

For example, you received an email saying there will be some work in 3 weeks along your road, and your internet connection **is not working** during the work.

Can I use present continuous in that case?

Comment: Firstly, Can you elaborate more on what you do mean by: If something is planned you have been imposed? Secondly, yes, basically present continuous is signalling that something is happening, either in the past, present or even in the future (will be +ing construction).

Answer (score 0):

You use the Present Continuous tense to indicate something that:

> Is happening now, frequently, and may continue into the future [Ref](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-continuous/)

The planning is being done in the present, but the internet will not stop working until the work starts in three weeks.

Because the internet is working now, and will continue to work up until the work starts, you would use the Future Tense to refer to its state of not working.

Comment: so we can't considerate that it is an arrangement as it is not you that has decided to make the work but why not there are going some work done as it has been planned before

Comment: @user5577 Sorry, to clarify: Are you asking "Why do we use the future tense if the work has been planned in the present?"

Comment: yes  and could you confirm first that it is not an arrangment because it is not something(the work and the non working internet  connection) that you have decided

Comment: @user557 I've edited the answer to include more information about your question. I'm not sure what you mean by "an arrangement," though.

Comment: so what I don't understand is why you can say I am visiting London in three weeks (i have booked my flight) and why you can't say the internet is not working during the work( i have recieved the email it is 100 per cent sure ) what is different

Comment: @user5577 Ah. I see your confusion. "Am going" is the [present continuous tense](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-continuous/). You would not use it to describe the internet not working because that situation has not started yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87342/discussion-between-user5577-and-rpeinhardt).

Comment: but the trip to London has not started yet  so what is the difference between those two

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with whether it has started: I think it is about intentional actions. I can say _I'm working next week_ because that is a choice I can make. But _working_ in the sense of "functioning correctly" is not an intentional state - it's contingent. I don't think this is the whole answer, because we can say _The festival is happening_, but I'm sure the answer is along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

To indicate that something is being done now or frequently.it is what you continue to do.

I am cooking.
She is bathing.

Comment: This does not provide any new information.